# Carnot cycle with isometric processes

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas

Consider the following slightly modified Carnot cycle with two extra isochoric processes for an ideal gas of adiabatic constant $\gamma$ working between temperatures $T_H>T_C$. A pV diagram is shown below

[image: Carnot Cycle]

It is parameterized by four different volume values, $V_A,V_B,V_C$ and $V_D$. These, in general, make it so that the adiabats don't exactly line up with the isotherms after the processes. I was also given that the heat in the isochoric processes is exchanged with the corresponding (hot or cold) reservoir. As such, I then computed the system's efficiency and got

$$\eta=1-\frac{T_C}{T_H}\left[\frac{\ln\frac{V_C}{V_D}+\frac{1}{\gamma-1}\left(\frac{T_HV_B^{\gamma-1}}{T_CV_C^{\gamma-1}}-1\right)}{\ln\frac{V_B}{V_A}+\frac{1}{\gamma-1}\left(1-\frac{T_CV_D^{\gamma-1}}{T_HV_A^{\gamma-1}}\right)}\right].$$

I am now tasked to show that this efficiency cannot be greater than the usual Carnot efficiency,

$$\eta_C=1-\frac{T_C}{T_H}.$$

This obviously amounts to showing that the term in between square brackets in my computed efficiency is greater than or equal to one. I, however, have no idea how to do this. Using only the ordering between the volumes and the temperatures,

$$0<V_A<V_B<V_C,\,T_C<T_H$$

I haven't been able to reach any satisfying conclusion regarding the inequality I'm trying to show. I know that the Clausius inequality (i.e. the Second Law) requires that $\eta\leq\eta_C$, but I'm not at all able to prove that using just the expression I found. Can anybody shine a light on the way forward?

Comment: Without trying to follow all the details, one observation I have is that by prematurely ending the adiabatic processes with isochoric processes aren't you reducing the area enclosed by the cycle? If so, then net work done in your modified Carnot cycle will be less than the Carnot cycle. If I'm right, that would make your cycle less efficient.

Comment: As it is currently written the $\gamma$ dependent terms do not depend of $V_B$ but have $V_D$ occurring twice. Is this correct or a typo?

Comment: @BySymmetry typo, fixed

Comment: @BobD Indeed. Intuitively it is quite simple to argue why, but I wanted to arrive at that conclusion from the general expression. This is mostly because the system I'm working with is actually not an ideal gas, and using that as a toy model would probably give me some insight as to how to proceed in the system I'm interested in.

Comment: @GabrielGolfetti Understood. I'll take another look at it.

Comment: @GabrielGolfetti Another thought. Instead of trying to start with the Carnot efficiency equation and attempting to see how it is modified by the expression in brackets, you might try starting with the general expression for efficiency, which also applies to the Carnot efficiency. The general expression is net work done divided by gross heat added. Or, all in terms of heat transfers, (QH-QL)/QH. Then you can focus on calculating the heat transfers during the isothermal and isochoric processes. Maybe that's what you did?

Comment: @GabrielGolfetti I would add you might use an ideal gas to simplify the calculations.

Comment: @BobD yeah, that's exactly what I did. The $T_C/T_H$ factor was factorized out because I thought it would be convenient.

Comment: Have you at least considered the limiting case where $V_A=V_D$ and $V_B=V_C$?  This is the case where the adiabats are completely replaced by isochors.  I think you will find that at least for this case, the term in brackets is > 1.

Comment: @ChesterMiller That's just the Stirling Cycle, yes

Answer (score 2):

The cycle shown in the figure can be created by starting with an ordinary Carnot cycle and appending a small "triangular" cycle at the upper left and at the lower right corners.  The appended cycles are both counter clockwise, each involving a negative amount of work, and the combination of Carnot cycle with the appended triangular cycles can be executed as a single continuous path.  Let $W_1$ be the work for the upper left triangular cycle, and $W_2$ be the work for the lower right triangular cycle.  Then, the efficiency of the path will be $$\eta=\frac{W_C-W_1-W_2}{Q_{HC}-W_1}$$where $W_C$ is the work for the Carnot cycle and $Q_{HC}$ is the heat added from the hot reservoir of the Carnot cycle.  Since $W_C<Q_{HC}$, this ratio must be less than $W_c/Q_{HC}$; this is because the same amount or more is subtracted from the numerator than from the denominator.